# CSS Error that is driving me wild

Tags: css, web

I am currently working on a website which was all going well until the css now thinks that the bottom of the page, even though i have positioned the image with

```
position:absolute;
bottom:0px;
```

is actually about 100 pixels above the bottom! I can't figure it out and my only answer could be because of how I am repeating things across the layout.The site can be found at [SemaphoreDesign](http://semaphoredesign.com/web-devel/oceanair) The paste bin for the style sheet is [here](http://pastebin.com/pf3hFVyZ) And for the HTML go [here](http://pastebin.com/1ni9U5kN) I really cannot figure out why the header and the endside are not at the bottom of the page and why there is a scroll bar.Thanks

Comment: are you talking about your footer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do a fixed position for these 2

```
#endside {
width:100%;
float:left;
height:112px;
position:fixed;
bottom:0px;
overflow:hidden;
background-image:url(images/main_09.png);
z-index-2;
}
#footer {
width:915px;
margin: 0 auto;
background-image:url(images/main_10.png);
height:112px;
position:fixed;
bottom:0px;
z-index:11;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mostly likely you're scrolling down when you see the problem?

You should be using `position:fixed` if you want it to not move when the user scrolls.

The reason you're getting a scrollbar in the first place is because you set your "content" `<div>` to `height:100%`, which means 100% of the window height. Since there's other elements the height exceeds the window height.

Comment: Ok that is what I thought could be the problem. How would I go about making that bottom bar be at the bottom and no visible if content exceeds the size of the page. Finding it hard to explain, but for example if the the content on one page added up to somewhere around 1000px in height but in the other it added up to 300px... I assume it would be something to do with no setting a height on the content area...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want to use `position:fixed`. This site has good CSS for footers you can copy:

http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might help:

HTML: http://pastebin.com/H0EauYeu
CSS: http://pastebin.com/mbV44Jef